# Finding a rider's origin station

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Hi: I have a query that I want to run that pulls back the date of a first ride and the depart station.

This is my query to date:

```
select 
Distinct(b.EmailAddress),
MIN(cast(b.DepartureDate as Date)) as "FirstRideDate"
from "REZ-RideHistory" as b
group by b.EmailAddress
```

The field for depart station is DepartStation.

I have tried to include it as b.DepartStation and it ends up returning all of the rides for the guest.

What I need the resulting output to look like is:

`EmailAddress | DepartureDate | FirstStation`

Any assistance would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a subquery including a 'row' field that is set based on DepartureDate asc, meaning that the first row will be the earliest date.  This will let you grab only the info attached to that record.

See below:

```
SELECT
b.EmailAddress,
b.FirstRideDate,
b.FirstStation
FROM (
  SELECT 
  row_number()over(partition by EmailAddress order by DepartureDate asc) as row,
  EmailAddress,
  DepartureDate as FirstRideDate,
  DepartStation as FirstStation
  FROM [REZ-RideHistory]
) b
WHERE b.row = 1
```

Comment: The query will run, but I'm getting duplicates.
So I added in the field name of RecordLocator, which is the same for the outbound and inbound travel.
So what I'm trying to define is the first time a person rode, along with the departure station. Maybe adding in RecordLocator will help.....

Comment: Duplicate Email Addresses?

Comment: Yeah our data is funky....

Here's what it looks like EmailAddress, RecordLocator, DepartStation, DepartureDate

And round trip tickets are sold like this:
xyz@mail.com, 1234, Station 1, June 16, 2018
xyz@mail.com, 1234, Station 2, June 16, 2018

so the outbound leg, and the inbound leg have the same recordlocator, but the departure time and departure stations are different...what I would need is the departurestation for the emailaddress, for the outbound leg's departstation

Comment: It shouldn't give duplicates since it is only pulling the first row and the row is assigned via EmailAddress - meaning that each email address should only have a single 'row = 1' value. That is odd.

Comment: I might try to pull it via record locator, and see if that works better

Comment: That worked thanks!